# Codeigniter: MP4 Video Upload not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, file-upload, upload

I am researching on a problem for long time but still could not find any solution.

I am uploading mp4 file using codeigniter. 
Before that I added mime type for mp4 in config/mimes.php.
I tried both: **`mp4 => video/mp4`** 
and
**`mp4 => array('video/mp4', 'video/3gpp')`**

Both of these works perfect in Local server but whenever I test this on the Live server then It always give the same error message "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.".

I tried one more thing. i.e. 
**`$config['allowed_types'] = "*";`**

It works perfect in both local and online server.

But I want just mp4 video type.

Anybody have some solution for this strange problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting it simply as $config['allowed_types'] = "mp4" ?

Comment: yes i tried $config['allowed_types'] = "mp4. but it works in local server only but does not in live server.

Comment: can you post the code you use to verify that file type?

Comment: Try and var_dump `$this->upload->file_type`. That should give you the mime type of the file your uploading as detected by codeigniter. The problem is most likely that your server is detecting the file as a different mime type to your local machine.

Comment: @Jeemusu Thank you very much for suggestion. You are correct. I checked this. Local server detects file_type as just "video/mp4". But online it detect file_type as "application/octet-stream". Not sure why but I got the solution. I added this mime in config and it works in both local and online server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I got solution of my Problem so I am writing this answer.

Mostly detection of mime types in local and online server are different.

In my case, *Local server was getting file_type as "video/mp4". But online server was detecting the mime type as 'application/octet-stream'.*

So I added both in array in the mime type list in my config folder:

**`'mp4' => array('video/mp4', 'application/octet-stream'),`**

Now it works perfectly in both local and online server.

Comment: Where should i add this array ??

mp4 => array('video/mp4', 'video/3gpp')

Comment: in config -> mimes.php

Answer (score 1):

If everything doesn't work, rearrange the allowed type order like this, placing the video format first:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4|jpg|png|'
```

It works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I depend on video mime file types when we upload video with extension mp4 but in CodeIgniter upload library use php function **finfo_file** for detect file_type by this function we get other file_type. Ex. I get **video/3gpp**

So I changed in config/mimes.php

**`'mp4'   =>   array('video/mp4', 'video/3gpp'),`**

and its working for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- I think you did everything but not getting ultimately output. You may follow the the below instruction that's solved my problem.
- Open your **php.ini** file using **sudo gedit /etc/php/<PHP_VERSION>/apache2/php.ini** for linux or go to your **php.ini** file.
- change **upload_max_filesize = 2M** to **upload_max_filesize = 100M** or as your choice.
- change **post_max_size = 2M** to **post_max_size = 100M** or as your choice like as **200M** or **500M**
- Now restart your **apache** using **sudo systemctl reload apache2** command or if you not a linux user (using **Xampp** or **Laragon** just stop your machine and restart again)
- It has solved my problem, hope it will also help you.