# issue with uploading mp4 video file even after changing the mime type to 'mp4' => video/mp4 and giving file type as mp4

Tags: php, codeigniter, video

I am trying to upload a mp4 video file using **codeigniter** file upload class as follows,

```
function do_upload_video()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4';
    $config['mimes'] = 'mp4';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $data['main_content'] ='admin/elements/add_video';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

    }
    else
    {
        $chapter_id=$this->session->userdata('chapter_id');
        redirect("/admin/elements/".$chapter_id);
    }
}
```

mime type given in mimes.php
            'mp4' => 'video/mp4'
further, I have also increased the file size in php.ini `post_upload_max size` and `upload_max_filesize` to sufficient level.

However when i am trying to upload a sample video file of size 8 MB with .mp4 extension it is showing error as "`The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed`".

```
Array ( [video] => Array ( [name] => daddyshome_paLrcx9H.mp4            [type]=>video/mp4 [tmp_name] => /tmp/php3xrVFp [error] => 0 [size] => 7350845 ) )
```

getting this on `print_r($_FILES)`

Comment: This might help you to solve your problem [Answer Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19738328/2598994)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed

```
      $config['mimes'] = 'mp4';
```

from my controller and it is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Set MIME type for MP4 in mime.php

```
'mp4' => array('video/mp4', 'application/octet-stream'),
```

Comment: nope, changed mime type and tried uploading again but same problem persists.

Comment: do `print_r($_FILES);` in your controller and check type.

Comment: Array ( [video] => Array ( [name] => daddyshome_paLrcx9H.mp4 [type] => video/mp4 [tmp_name] => /tmp/php3xrVFp [error] => 0 [size] => 7350845 ) )  getting this on print_r($_FILES)