# CodeIgniter upload fails - filetype is not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm keep getting error `The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed`, when I try to upload MP4 movie file.

This is my upload function

```
public function upload_post() {
        $config['upload_path'] = ROOT_DIR . $dataBasePath;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'avi|mov|mp4|jpeg|jpg|png';
        $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
        $config['max_size'] = '80000';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) {
            $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
            if ($uploadData) {
                $this->response([
                   'data' => $uploadData
                ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
            } else {
                $this->response([
                    'status' => false,
                    'message' => 'failed'
                ], REST_Controller::HTTP_CONFLICT);
            }
        } else {
            var_dump($_FILES);
            die();
            $this->response([
                'status' => false,
                'errors' => ['error' => $this->upload->display_errors()]
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_CONFLICT);
        }
}
```

When I upload a file and `var_dump($_FILES)` data if upload fails, this is the result

```
array (size=1)
  'userFile' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '1-video.mp4' (length=11)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 1
      'size' => int 0
```

The result of `var_dump(get_mime_by_extension($_FILES['userFile']['name']))` is following

```
'video/mp4'
```

I have also checked my mimes.php file and I have entire

```
'mp4'   =>  array('video/mp4', 'application/octet-stream'),
```

I don't know what else should I do or check in order to upload a file successfully? Uploading images works OK.
 If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729381/codeigniter-mp4-video-upload-not-working

Comment: you can try with $config['allowed_types'] = "*";

Comment: if i do that, then i get another error:
A problem was encountered while attempting to move the uploaded file to the final destination

Comment: for that use FCPATH instead of ROOT_DIR

Comment: how large is the file and what is your post_max_size and upload_max_filesize? show your code for defining ROOT_DIR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is working in my code Perfectly and uploaded file move to my folder.

**controller**

```
public function addd(){

   $images = "property.".pathinfo($_FILES['images']['name'], 
       PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

   $addimg = array(
            "images" =>  $images,
        );

    $this->db->insert("tbl_name",$addimg);

    $uploadPath = "./html/images/property";

    $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|mp4';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

    $config['file_name'] = "property";
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('images');
    $this->upload->display_errors();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

added both in array in the mime type list in my config folder:

`'mp4' => array('video/mp4', 'application/octet-stream'),`

Comment: it will chek mime type of file

Comment: check file type and file mime type are same or not?

Comment: yes they are the same... I start to assume, that there is a problem with file, even though that file is normally playable, etc...

Comment: well have you tried a different mp4 file to rule that out? @Valor_

Answer (score 0):

Change mp4 to MP4

`$config['allowed_types'] = 'MP4'`

Comment: didn't help... I start to assume, that there is a problem with file, even though that file is normally playable, etc...